# React Native responsive image width while width/height ratio of image keeps the same

Tags: react-native

I want a React Native Image to have a width of 50% of the available screen-width, no modification to width:height ratio of the image.

Any hints how to solve this?

Comment: I think [react-native-fit-image](https://github.com/huiseoul/react-native-fit-image) is useful for you.

Comment: Have a look at [react-native-scalable-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-scalable-image)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use resize mode `cover` and set the width to ScreenWidth / 2 you can retrive the screen width using [Dimensions](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.32/docs/dimensions.html#content) component

```
//Get screen width using Dimensions component 
var {width} = Dimensions.get('window');
//....
//In image style 
image:{
   width: width * 0.5
}
//In render function
<Image resizeMode = 'cover' style = {styles.image}/>
```

**Edit adding overflow**

```
//add overflow : visible 
<Image resizeMode = 'cover' style = {[styles.image,{overflow: 'visible'}]}/>
```

Comment: thank you, so for now this at least let's me have the correct width. When just passing a width style-property to the image, the whole image seems to collapse and does not apply any height values to the image. if i pass some height property manually, it works just fine. as i don't want to have a fixed height on each image, is there some workaround to have it "really responsive" by just applying this width?

I set up some RN playground with border helpers and already including your solution [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/OWsKaQ)

Comment: adding `overlow : visible` to style will solve the problem

Comment: never would have figured that out that this was an overflow problem, thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Local images can be rendered without giving a fixed width and height but, for remote images you must provide dimensions as react-native cant calculate them on runtime.
So, the following works for me

```
<View style={styles.thumbContainer}>
      <Image source={{uri: "REMOTE_IMAGE_URI}} style={styles.thumbnail} />
</View>
```

and apply following styles.

```js
thumbContainer: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 400,
},
thumbnail: {
    flex: 1,
    width: undefined,
    height: undefined,
    resizeMode: 'cover'
},
```

Answer (score 5):

This code worked for me

```
        <Image
            style={{width: '100%', height: 100}}
            resizeMode={'center'}
            source={{}}
        />
```

Answer (score 4):

The verified answer didn't work for me but gave me a good idea.

It probably didn't work because my images are within a ScrollView.

Since images require a width and a height, my solution has been to get the width of the screen and:
a) For image width: multiply screen width by % of the screen width I want my image to take. 
b) For image height: multiply screen width by % of the screen width I want my image to take by height/width aspect ratio.

```
const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');

<Image style={{ width: width * 0.5, height: width * 0.5 * 2.16 }}
       source={require("everydaycheckmobile/images/introduction/5-overviewdark.png")}
/>
```

Works nicely, but it will be necessary to dynamically define the % of width screen you want the image to take to make it work good responsively and for various orientations.