# Logo Gets Cropped In Other Devices

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist, react-native-image

I Am New To React Native And I am Facing A Issue With Responsive Image. This Code is working fine on my phone But when I try it on another phone The Image Gets Cropped In The Sides.

I Tried The Following solutions

[Responsive image in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52675852/responsive-image-in-react-native)

[React Native responsive image width while width/height ratio of image keeps the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39311596/react-native-responsive-image-width-while-width-height-ratio-of-image-keeps-the/39312040)

This is The Complete Code https://snack.expo.io/SuHBzDnNi

```
 return(
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.Touch} onPress={this.MoveNextPage}>
           <Image resizeMode="contain" source={require("../logo.png")} style={styles.logo}/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </SafeAreaView>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        flex:1,
        height:Dev_Height,
        width:Dev_Width,
        justifyContent:"center",
        alignItems:"center",
        backgroundColor:"#121212"
    },
    logo:{
      height:"100%",
      width:"100%"
    },
    Touch:{
      justifyContent:"center",
      alignItems:"center",
      height:"22%",
      width:"40%"
    }
})
```

Thank You : )

Comment: use resizeMode of image  in this case...use contain
<Image source={{uri:item["originalImageUrl"]}} style={{height:"80%",width:"80%",borderRadius:15}} resizeMode="contain"/>

Comment: Ok Let me give it a try

Comment: @Pramod That Doesn't Help : (

Comment: When i put resizeMode contain its not cropping image its getting fit in the container as per aspect ratio 
Snack : https://snack.expo.io/@msbot01/reactnativecode.com

Comment: @Pramod actually it works on snack . But it doesn't in my physical mobile .

Comment: one solution is to give fixed width and height instead of %tage. Get the width of the screen divide the content and image part accordingly

Comment: ok Let Me Give It A Try